# Populate one DataFrame column from another, but every nth row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to populate every 2nd value from a DataFrame df2 column into DataFrame df1 column using `iloc`, however, I'm getting alternate NULL values in the result. How do I get continuous values without the NULL values?

For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col2': list('ABCD')})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]})

df1.col1 = df2.iloc[::2]
```

Output:

```
| col1     | col2           |
| -------- | -------------- |
|   2      |     A          |
|  NULL    |     B          |
|   6      |     C          |
|  NULL    |     D          |
```

Expected output:

```
| col1     | col2           |
| -------- | -------------- |
|   2      |     A          |
|   6      |     B          |
|   8      |     C          |
|   10     |     D          |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the `Series` to a list and it should work for you, likewise:

```
df1.col1 = df2.iloc[::2].tolist()
```

Output:

```
| col1     | col2           |
| -------- | -------------- |
|   2      |     A          |
|   6      |     B          |
|   8      |     C          |
|   10     |     D          |
```

Comment: Thank you, this works !

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df2.iloc[::2, :]
```

Which will give you:

```
   col1
0     2
2     6
4    10
6    14
```

Comment: Thank for the answer.I tried your code, it gave me the exact same results. Turns out, `.iloc[::2]` and `.iloc[::2, :]` are the same.